# One div and its content on website loading last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

UPDATE : With help from @TrueBlueAussie,
Yes, since I am not hiding the div, the code below is useless. So ignoring it (The script I used below) , is there a proper solution to my problem.

I have a website, http://frankvinyl.com/

It is a wordpress website. The featured image at the top, it loads after all the website is loaded.

I tried for different solutions for loading the DIV first, but its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#main1").show(); 
    });
```

The problem is, the content of `#main1` loads after all the website and content is loaded. I just want to load the div with the flow as the rest of the content.

Have been tweaking around but cannot find a appropriate solution.

Comment: `$("#main1").show();` will have no effect as the div is not hidden. The problem is purely the asynchronous loading of the image. What is the desired effect you want? Smooth unveil *once the image loads*?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie how do i achieve asynchronous loading of the image ?

Comment: It *is* async... That's how browsers work... Your options are to inline the image in the styling (as base64 data), or unveil it in a nice way when the image loads (images have a load event).

Comment: Okay, now we have established the problem (a basic feature of webpages is that images are queued for loading *as they are found in the page*, and this is just a huge/slow image), what end result are you after? Hide the entire page until that image is loaded? Not show the image until it is loaded, then fade it in? Something else?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie , what I want to achieve is, as the rest of the image are loading (the four sub featured images below the top featured image )(the image loading portions of it gradually as the site loads), I want the same thing to happen with the top image too.

Answer (score -2):

You are waiting for the document to be ready in your jquery.

Try putting   $("#main1").show(); before the document ready.
Don't know if it will work, it has been a long time :p

Comment: This suggestion is not useful. If you view the source of the page you will see that the `div` in question is not hidden in the first place. it is purely down to the image loading.

Comment: Oh, well then i suggest that he uses a jquery plugin that loads the page first.

Comment: I think you mean a jQuery plugin that loads that massive image first, then the page :)

Comment: or the page then the image, just preloading it and then showing the website.
Plugin Oloader does this, use the function on the body of html. Should work..

Comment: Try this one - May be it will help you - http://www.voidcanvas.com/demo/?art=http://voidcanvas.com/how-to-check-if-all-the-images-of-a-page-are-loaded-using-simple-jquery/&demoid=7382check-image-load#.VHSzyntSKeI